# Content approval and workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm new at SharePoint and I'm trying to find a way to do both content approval and workflow approval at the same time -in a single pass. I don't have access to SharePoint Designer or InfoPath at this point in time and will be moving to Office 365 by next year.

My questions would be:

1. Can I do both content approval and workflow approval in one pass (not in 2 steps)? If so, how?
2. Will any change affect how things will behave when switching to Office 365?
3. Why does the content approval starts off the workflow approval?

I've been looking for a solid answer for the last few weeks and just keep hitting walls. Any help with item will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that my frustration is that these two processes do not work together. The content approval process does not send emails to those in charge of approving and the workflow approval does not do versioning on its own. I'm not sure that having these two active and just approving the content approval will do what I need it to do, as by doing this the workflow shows as canceled and the approval status is marked as approved.